# Android 4.4 - HttpClient - TLS - accept all certificate

Tags: android, ssl

I'm developing an app. targeting **Android 4.4 (API level 19)** and I want, during my HTTP exchanges, to accept all certificates in case of HTTPS connections. It's an explicit choice because my app is a like of scanner.

All the example that I have found, use the fact that the class "*org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory*" possess a contructor accepting a SSL context and a Hostname verifier.

The problem is that the implementation of the "SSLSocketFactory" class in API level 19 do not have this constructor version anymore and I cannot find a way to provide a custom TrustManager to the class "SSLSocketFactory".

Is it still possible to achieve my goal with HttpClient in Android API level 19 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trust SSL Factory:

```
public class TrustSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public TrustSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new TrustSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
```

(This is the code I use currently. Note that its **very unsafe so only use in development**)

I cant remember where I got this code from, so I cant credit the original author.

Comment: Worked for HttpClient 4.2.1